# Using C2DM to receive notification from gmail server

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'd like my Android app to receive notification when new messages arrive in my
gmail account.
I realize that the Android gmail client does not broadcast
notification when it receives messages. Instead I want to utilize the
gmail server's Cloud to Device Messaging capabilities to do this. I
read the article at http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ - the only
"missing piece" for me is to understand how my app sends a
registration ID to the gmail server. Can someone please point me in
the right direction?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I'm presume that the stock Android GMail client gets notifications from the GMail servers via C2DM - so there must be a defined interface to send a registration ID to the server - but what is that interface?

Comment: I don't see how this could work. C2DM receivers are designed to listen to intents specifically sent to them (with the right target package and permissions), and C2DM broadcasters are designed to send intents to specific applications. GMail isn't going to be configured to send C2DM broadcasts to your arbitrary application, and your application isn't going to have permissions to receive those broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

While Android's GMail client (and Contacts, Calendar, etc.) uses a push style notification system, it's not C2DM, as that is only available on Android 2.2+ devices for now.
That being the case, I don't think Google provides a C2DM service to receive push notifications of received e-mails, nor do I think they will, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. It appears that Google has been using the XMPP channel for push notifications for a while now, which C2DM seems to be an extension of. As near as I can tell, what's changed is that the API has been opened up to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

The native Gmail client does not use C2DM AFAIK. It maintains a socket connection to the mail server, similar to Exchange.